# Why do these strings evaluate to false even when i enter them exactly right?

Tags: java, eclipse, string

I am writing a simple program to get to grips with using the Scanner in Java. The program has a stored value for user_1 and asks the user to provide 
the String variable username which is then checked against user_1 using the == operator, however even when username matches user_1 it still evaluates to false. I'm sure I must be missing something simple, any help would be appreciated. I even added the line printing both variable just to double check they are the same!!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HelloWorld {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String user_1 = ("lucasRHCP");

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your username: ");
    String username = input.nextLine();

    System.out.println(user_1 + " " + username);

    if (username == user_1){
        System.out.println("True");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("False");
    }
}   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

NEVER compare objects (and String is am object) with `==`, use `equals()` method

Comment: To add to your reason for this, it's because `==` compares objects. Primitives like the `int`, `byte`, `long`, `boolean`, `enum` are primitives, and so on.

Comment: @CoderMusgrove I left that for the OP to discover

Answer (score 2):

With `==` you compare whether two *objects* are the same, not whether their value is. You want to compare their values, so you need to use `.equals()`:

```
if (username.equals(user_1)) {
  System.out.print("True");
} else {
  System.out.print("False");
}
```

It's like comparing two red identical looking car, they are identical but not the same thing. In java two variables can be both the same thing or two distinct, alike things.

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare Strings in java using ==

You should use the String class methods

```
username.equals(user_1);
```